# Question about limits in normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

If $(X, ||\cdot||)$ is a normed space and $(\delta_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $V$ converging to $\delta\in V$, is it true that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}||\delta_n||= ||\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_n||.$$

I've been trying to come up with a proof as it was used in a certain part of the lecture notes I'm reading but I have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

The triangle inequality can be modified easily to give you $$\big| \|\delta_n\| - \|\delta\| \big| \le \|\delta_n - \delta\| \to 0$$ so that $\|\delta_n\| \to \|\delta\|$.